# Update breaks CUDA and nvidia-driver-390!

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, dell, cuda

I have an old Dell XPS laptop with a NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 550M.
I managed to get CUDA® and OpenCL working just fine, with `clinfo` displaying CUDA® as a platform. However, I recently upgraded the kernel or something with `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`, and it totally broke!
Now BOINC does not detect any GPU and `clinfo` does not show anything!

Comment: I only see a statement. Mind that you can always pick an older kernel from GRUB is that is the issue. Otherwise you will need to add more details about; error message are useful for something like this.

Comment: Well, I looked everywhere and I only saw weird solutions that were difficult and time-consuming. However, the apparent solution is to just use an old kernel and let Ubuntu do its thing.

Answer (score -1):

After tons of effort and trial-and-error, this eventually fixed it:

1. Back up your files
2. Reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
3. Once booted into the fresh install, install an old kernel (like 5.15) with apt.
4. Reboot and select "Advanced options for Ubuntu", then select the old kernel.
5. Purge new, incompatible kernels with `apt purge`
6. Go to "Additional Drivers" and select the proprietary driver. Let it do its thing and reboot when prompted"
7. Update the system with `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo snap refresh`
8. Check clinfo
9. Reboot again
10. All Done!
    The NVIDIA® driver should work.

I once reinstalled the driver via CLI (after installing it though the GUI)and it improved some stuff(like more NVIDIA® apps and OpenCL for CPU as well)
However, installing through the GUI first appears to be absolutely mandatory.